# Use "Assert.IsTrue" for position in relation to object

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium-webdriver

Goal:
When you press on a customized [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) you enter to a webpage and the screen is located in a specific position that you have the text **"Padding - Shorthand Property"**.

The goal is to use `Assert.IsTrue` that the padding -shorthand property and its content is located inside of the visible computer screen.

Problem:

I don't know if it possibly to create this approach using `Selenium` with `C#`.

I don't know where to start.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to get value of `Location` property of `WebElement`? And compare them to needed coordinates?

Comment: not yet, I didn't about this

Answer (score 0):

There's not a good way to do this with just Selenium. We'll have to execute some Javascript using [`JavascriptExecutor`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). We find the desired element and pass it to `IsElementInView()` which calls some Javascript functions to return the top/bottom/left/right of the element and compare them to the height and width of the browser window.

- If `top < 0`, the element is off the screen above.
- If `bottom > height`, the element is off the screen below.
- If `left < 0`, the element is off the screen left.
- If `right > width`, the element is off the screen right.

If any of the above are true, then the element is off the screen. Otherwise, the element is on the screen.

```
class Program
{
    static IWebDriver driver;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        String searchText = "Padding - Shorthand Property";
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp");
        IWebElement e = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h2[text()=" + searchText + "]"));
        Console.WriteLine(IsElementInView(e));
    }

    public static Boolean IsElementInView(IWebElement e)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        Double top = (Double)jse.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top", e);
        Double bottom = (Double)jse.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom", e);
        long left = (long)jse.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().left", e);
        long right = (long)jse.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().right", e);
        long width = (long)jse.ExecuteScript("return window.innerWidth");
        long height = (long)jse.ExecuteScript("return window.innerHeight");
        if (top < 0 || bottom > height || left < 0 || right > width)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```